# Spotify API get last listend to

Tags: api, spotify

I am trying to get a list, of the last listened **tracks, playlists and albums**.
All I could find were [the recently played tracks](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/#endpoint-get-recently-played).

Do you know any way to get all the Information?

Answer (score 0):

No, that's the only way to do it. You just have the endpoint you already found and can't access the last played albums, artists or playlists.

Maybe the endpoint to get a users top tracks could help you achieve what you want?

Answer (score 0):

You can also get the `context` that the track was listened to within.

The recently played tracks endpoint returns a list of [PlayHistoryObject](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/#object-playhistoryobject). One of the fields on this is `context`, a [ContextObject](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/#object-contextobject).

The context object will tell you whether the track was listened to in the context of an Artist Page, a Playlist, an individual Album, or a Show (I think a podcast?)

You can also get the Spotify URI of the context